Restarting a PowerShell script after the last process is closed with variables
I found a script for 1 to 10, but I need it for usernames.
I like to start a new browser, for every user, after I close the browser for the previous user. After all users I want to start over again.
The script I have so far seems to work, but the users seem to be picked "random", I believe the items from the collection are not on hold while edge is still active and waiting for the user to end.
while ($true) { $collection = "aap","noot","mies" foreach ($item in
$collection) {
    $Procs = Get-Process msedge | ? {$_.SI -eq (Get-Process -PID $PID).SessionId} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (($procs).Count -eq 0) {
        Start-Process -FilePath msedge https://outlook.office.com/mail/$item/junkemail Write-Host $item
    } }  }


are you looking for something like Wait-Process? Also, if I may suggest adding a Start-Sleep in there to avoid a tight loop

I need to check the junkmail folders for over 30 users. Opening them all at once is very have on memory for my machine. So I thought if I open them one by one the memry load is much less. But I need some time to check if it is spam or not, so I should pause it, so if edge start just after I close a previous version I have that problem solved also. The script above seems to do almost that, but if I wait for a while it's random which one is the next.
